# Access on buttons in NSTableCellView

Tags: nstableviewcell

In my macOS XCode-project I addd a [button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv56J.png) to my Table Cell View which I want to access programmatically.

When I connect the button to an IBOutlet or IBAction I get following error message when I try to build my project:

*/Users/homefolder/Desktop/myapp/myapp/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: The myButton outlet from the ViewController to the NSButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.*

Same for IBAction which is self-explaining.
Can you tell me how to access the button for each Table Cell View?

PS: Edit:

There is almost no code to show:

I added an IBOutlet in ViewController.swift:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var remove_BTN: NSButtonCell!
```

Then I get the error as described above.

Same for the IBAction:

```
    @IBAction func remove_BTN(_ sender: Any) {}
```

Comment: You should show some code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: added to question